# document.getElementById('rockImg').src == "rock.png" doesn't seem to get executed in if() block

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started studying javascript. What I wanna do with the following code is to switch two images as I click the image with id `rockImg`.

I successfully changed one to another with a single statement of `document.getElementById('rockImg').src = "rock_happy.png"`; but couldn't swap the two images by clicking the image.

AFAIK, the `if-else` statement syntax does not have anything wrong; to make sure, I referred this website: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yyde5c(v=vs.94).aspx.

Is the problem on the comparison statement? Because it works properly when run with `ocument.getElementById('rockImg').src = "rock_happy.png"` only, this is the only case I can think out.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>iRock - The Virtual Pet Rock</title>
    <script>
    function change(){
        // alert('yay! it changed!')
        if(document.getElementById('rockImg').src == 'rock.png'){
            document.getElementById('rockImg').src = "rock_happy.png";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('rockImg').src = "rock.png";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="margin-top:100px; text-align:center;">
        <img id="rockImg" src="rock.png" alt="iRock" onclick="change()"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: +both image names are correct!

Comment: Share a fiddle of your work and it will be easy for the others to see whats happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The src property always returns the entire image URL, not the relative path so the if condition would fail always.

Use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) instead to get exact attribute value

```
function change(){
    var img = document.getElementById('rockImg');
    if(img.getAttribute('src') == 'rock.png'){
        img.setAttribute('src', "rock_happy.png");
    }
    else{
        img.setAttribute('src', "rock.png");
    }
}
```

---

You can reduce the number of lines of code by using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) statement.

```
function change(){
    var img = document.getElementById('rockImg');
    img.setAttribute('src',img.getAttribute('src') == 'rock.png' ? "rock_happy.png" : "rock.png");
}
```